# How to use fabric to get crash logs of application?

Tags: android, crash-reports, crashlytics

i have added plugins into eclipse of fabric and whenever i click on the blue icon of fabric it ask to login but i didn't get any username password for it.

So please tell me how to Sign-up for fabric and how to implmenet it in application to gt crash logs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sign-up from [here](https://try.crashlytics.com/). When you login using crashlytics plugin, the plugin show you how to integrate SDK to your project step by step.

Comment: but i am not getting any main to create account

Comment: You will get mail that contains link to create new account. Probably you receive two mail : Second mail has the link.